How do I use a local Maven repository that is in a weird location for Gradle using Windows
I have my maven setup for the path i:\ds\.m2_repo so I try to setup gradle with
repositories{
  maven{
    url: "file://i:/ds/.m2_repo"
  }
}

Now when I go to the path file://i:/ds/.m2_repo in explorer the path works fine, however, when I try to run gradle build it can't seem to find the version and throws an error. If I revert to an older version that is in the global repo everything works great. is there something I am missing with how to do this in Windows?
Additional Code that might help
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "me.package:my-parent:3.3.2-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}
dependency{
   implementation "me.package:my-starter-webmvc"
}

Error message
* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':photon:compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':my-project:compileClasspath'.

   > Could not find me.package:my-starter-webmvc:.

     Required by:

         project :my-project



Do you use old Gradle file or new Gradle.kts file?

build.gradle but if there is a difference I don't mind switching to kotlin
